# How useful are basic economics (elasticity / consumer & producer theory) in real life?

Tags: consumer-theory, elasticity, producer-theory, oligopoly, classical-economics

I am thinking how these concepts will be applied in the industries / at a job.

For example I could see `elasticity` as useful in projecting the outcomes of supply shocks.

Say, there is a risk management department in a big company, which foresees alternative outcomes and hedges risks accordingly. But I see most elasticities are measured poorly in reality.

Or say the investment department looks at changes in the commodity market to work out whether there has been a `supply shock` or `demand shock`. (I think this might even be done simply by looking at the futures exchange)

I know that `consumer theory` has special application in labour markets, but don't see its uses anywhere else.

Do firms really work out their `residual demand` (under `oligopoly`)? For example, does Microsoft really does all the math to figure out Windows' share of pie with MacOS?

I know economics predictions are "coarse-grained", but under what degree of certainty is a company willing to act on it?

I am figuring out the direction I am headed as I study ECON, but has been fairly clueless. Please mention any advanced topics if you think it would help with an answer.

Comment: what do you mean by basic economics when it comes to elasticity etc? For example, elasticity is widely used almost everywhere in business or public administration but what counts as basic elasticity? With passing101 econ, without major in CS or DS and a lot of extra self study you wont be able to actually estimate any elasticity in real life. Similarly, large firms will use IO modeling and consumer choice theory directly or indirectly in building pricing models etc but none of it can be done with something that you learn in 101 econ

Comment: econ 101 is meant to give you basic building blocks for further study and maybe impart some lessons that can be generally useful IRL like consider opportunity cost, dont get confused with nominal variables, understanding the importance of division of labor or basic reasoning for trade but it has next to nothing when it comes to something that can be practically directly implemented (apart the general lessons) in business or public admin

Comment: @1muflon1 "*large firms will use IO modeling and consumer choice theory directly or indirectly*" I dispute this claim.

Comment: @Giskard  you can dispute it but its a fact see for example this CNN article https://edition.cnn.com/2019/03/13/tech/amazon-economists/index.html. PS: I am not claiming they copy paste models from lets say Belleflamme, but they use IO and consumer choice theory in modeling similarly like let's say CB modelers use empirical structural models that are informed by macro theory.

Comment: @1muflon1 Your "proof" of this "fact" is an example that has no IO or consumer choice theory in it? Or maybe I missed a part? Can you please quote it?

Comment: @Giskard but the source state for example that those economists are working on data based strategic decision making. That by definition part of IO. Yes there is no concrete examples there because the models are proprietary and the article is not but from the description I believe it’s clear

Comment: Is this academic journal level proof, or would you say a revision is needed? I am pretty sure you can find "*data based strategic decision making*" in most business school curriculums, and it will have no math beyond ratios.

Comment: @Giskard yes but I am not talking about business curriculums. For example, in my PhD courses almost half of pupils are physicists by their Bc education. That’s because in many countries in Bc econ students don’t learn enough math and mathematical modeling. That does not mean economics is not heavy on mathematical modeling. I do know anecdotally that they do use IO and CT informed models but not something it’s pulled from a textbook from past classmate that works for Netflix which also hires PhD econs. Btw also demand itself is broadly speaking part of choice theory so estimating

Comment: Price elasticity of demand while imposing some structural restrictions of your model is also using choice theory and that is routinely done by large business nowadays. Business do not publish their models in academic journals so what kind of evidence you suggest I provide? When I was working at Dutch CPB we also did not published our model for all forecasts but we did not made those numbers up. Central banks also don’t publish all their models

Comment: Did you use choice theory models at the Dutch Consumer Protection Bureau? Not something that is loosely related or "could be called that" but actual consumer choice theory?

Comment: @Giskard yes in a sense we had structural macro models with fundamentals based in choice theory, not in a sense we would try to estimate some highly abstract model from MWG. Also we did not worked with pure theoretical models at all but empirical models especially structural ones are based on theory

Comment: Of course you always have to use empirics, but in my experience most of the theory is replaced by very simple rules of thumb, as you cannot get most of the requisite data. Of course they will still call it consumer theory and such, because as they write in the article you linked, it is good advertising. Perhaps I am wrong! but in my experience these models are not frequently used at big firms, or even government agencies. Clearly, you are quite good and will have a nice academic career; why do you insist on this stuff being useful outside of it?

Comment: @Giskard 1. I am not insisting on it. There is a lot of practical value in use of a models when they are appropriately tailored to a specific situation in my opinion. 2. If I was not clear enough, I stated multiple times that its not like those companies use the models that appear in MWG or Varian as they are. But numerical modeling (which requires theoretical model) and empirical modeling (which benefits immensely from having theoretical model) has in my opinion great value to gov and business. You might disagree maybe Netflix, Amazon etc will come to regret hiring all those PhDs

Comment: I heard netflix has some problems already maybe thats due to bad decision making caused by bad modeling. I do not think so, but large business, especially silicon valley business, do use it directly or indirectly. Perhaps to their peril lets see

Comment: I agree with 1muflon1 here. Many two-sided platforms such as Uber and Lyft directly estimate elasticity curves. There are several benefits, which include setting prices and estimating consumer surplus. There are several papers of academic quality such as the following: https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w22627/w22627.pdf and https://john-joseph-horton.com/papers/uber_price.pdf. In my experience, these analyses also often come up in economic consulting.

Comment: It seems to me that both of you are conflating "models" with "IO and consumer choice models". I do not doubt that "models" exist, nor that companies estimate elasticity, nor that academics use company data to estimate IO and consumer choice models. What I do doubt is that companies use IO and consumer choice models that are actually those things and not just "related somehow".